# Work done in a $pV$ diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, temperature, work

From what I gather, work done in a $pV$ diagram is the area under the curve. I have this figure here:

[image]

The solution says the quantity of work in A is greater than that in B. I am kinda confused, aren't the area of $\Delta iAf$ and $\Delta iBf$ the same?

Comment: Where are you defining your area? It should be going all the way to the horizonal axis.

Comment: Yes, the work done is the area ***under*** the curve. There is more space under curve A (all the way down to the axis) than under curve B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area under curve A:

[image]

Area under curve B:

[image]

Remember that "*under*" means all the way down to the horizontal axis. The work formula is an integral, $$W=\int p \mathrm dV,$$ and integrals work by summing up all the infinitely many infinitely thin columns that stand on the axis and reach up to the curve.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what areas you mean, but the work ($W=\int pdV$) on the system for path A is the area under the projection of A onto the V-axis, and the work done on the system for path B is the area under the projection of B onto the V-axis.

The area under A is greater than B, thus more work is done on the system for process A than B.

Hope this helps.